# Github Action - AWS CodeDeploy Succeeded but in EC2 created the modified file

Tags: amazon-ec2, github-actions, aws-code-deploy

i'm setting up the Github Action, AWS EC2, CodeDeploy. All the configuration seems working well. But excepts one thing. I can not understand and how can i solve it. If someone have experiences about this please help me.

I'm using:

- EC2 Rhel 8
- Node project (VueJs framework)

This is my cicd.yml file

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
    - paymentV2
    
name: Deploy VueJS to Amazon ECS
#on: [push]

jobs:
  deploy:
    name: Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: ['12.x']
        appname: ['staging-aws-codedeploy']
        deploy-group: ['staging']
        repo: ['project/MyProject']

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      # Configure AWS credentials
      - name: Configure AWS credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws-region: ap-southeast-1

      # Deploy to AWS
      - name: Deploy to AWS
        run: |
          aws deploy create-deployment \
          --application-name ${{ matrix.appname }} \
          --deployment-config-name CodeDeployDefault.OneAtATime \
          --deployment-group-name ${{ matrix.deploy-group }} \
          --file-exists-behavior OVERWRITE \
          --description "GitHub Deployment for the ${{ matrix.appname }}-${{ github.sha }}" \
          --github-location repository=${{ matrix.repo }},commitId=${{ github.sha }}
```

This is my appspec.yml

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /var/www/MyProject
hooks:
  ApplicationStart:
    - location: scripts/application_start.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
  #scripts/application_start.sh
  #cd /var/www/MyProject
  #npm run build
```

This is the log from Github action & CodeDeploy AWS

[image]

I've tried editing the **Vision.vue** file and created the pull request on Github. Everything was working well. But one thing i'm confusing is why the modified file is existed. Please refer the image below

[image]

=> What am i expected is the modified file shouldn't have existed. I thought that Github should be automatically run **git pull** to get all new source code.
I've some more research and found out --file-exists-behavior with OVERWRITE but it seems not working as i want.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/deploy/create-deployment.html

==> Once again, i have no experience about CD by Github action & CodeDeploy. Everyone please help me and advice me the right thing. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

After a period of learning, I understood that appspect and buildspec.yaml were just the way to build and deploy, but for the pull code, I used webhook (aws codebuild, AWS Code Pipeline, Github webhook) or schedule (crontab). And i've decided to user crontab for my project, scheduling to pull new source code every hours. Hope this sharing can help anyone. Tks